# How do you create an array from variables derived from a foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, foreach

I'm certain this is VERY simple, but being new and not knowing what I'm doing I can't quite get it on my own.

I am trying to create an array of wordpress post ID's that is derived from a simple foreach loop.

Basically I have this as my code:

```
$omit_these_quizzes = array();    
foreach ( $filtered_pass as $single_quiz ) {
    $quiz_id_number =  $single_quiz['quiz'];
    $omit_these_quizzes[] = $quiz_id_number;
}
```

I would like to take each of the resulting $quiz_id_number 's and have then end up in array that looks like this:

```
$omit_these_quizzes = array(8195,8193);
```

However, I keep ending up with an array that only contains the variable from the very last foreach loop, instead of them all. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code looks fine, so either `$filtered_pass` contains only one id, or the result in `$omit_these_quizzes ` *is* okay, but you inspect/process it in the wrong way.

Comment: I believe your code is supposed to work correctly, but you can try this. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine.But if you want alternative try this:
see here for [in_array](https://www.php.net/in_array) and [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php).

```
$omit_these_quizzes = array();    
foreach ( $filtered_pass as $single_quiz ) 
{
   $quiz_id_number =  $single_quiz['quiz'];
   if(!in_array($quiz_id_number ,$omit_these_quizzes))
   {
     array_push($omit_these_quizzes, $quiz_id_number);
   }
}
```

hope it's help you.

Comment: Thanks! I guess the if statement prevents my array from doubling up on id's? That seems to keep things clean and tidy. Thanks for the added bonus :-)

Comment: The if statement that you threw in helped me out tremendously with another piece of code. Double thanks to you.

Comment: you always welcome and yes the if statement prevents duplicate entry.

Answer (score 1):

This work?

```
$omit_these_quizzes = array();    
foreach ( $filtered_pass as $single_quiz ) {
    $quiz_id_number =  $single_quiz['quiz'];
    array_push($omit_these_quizzes, $quiz_id_number);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It does exactly what I was hoping for :-)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are creating a new array in each loop, that's why you end up with an array containing just a single element...
Use:

```
$omit_these_quizzes = array();    
foreach ( $filtered_pass as $single_quiz ) 
{
    $quiz_id_number =  $single_quiz['quiz'];
    array_push($omit_these-quizzes, $quiz_id_number);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This code did exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for explaining why my old one wasn't working ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. Inspect your $filtered_pass variable by calling var_dump($filtered_pass); may be it contain only one subarray.

Comment: I did check my $filtered_pass array, although I was using return print_r to check instead of var_dump like you suggested. Is var_dump the 'correct' way of checking?  There were indeed multiple sub-arrays btw.